# Seeing Indy Traffic in Fiddler

Tags: delphi, indy

I think this is an easy question for someone familiar with Indy.  I'm using Delphi 2010 and Indy 10.  I am trying to get off the ground accessing an SSL web service.  I think it will be a lot easier if I can get Fiddler to see my HTTP traffic.  I have seen posts on StackOverflow that indicate it's no big thing to get Fiddler to see your Indy traffic, that you just have to configure the port to make it work.  My question is how do you do that?

Here is my code so far:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var slRequest: TStringList;
    sResponse,
    sFileName: String;
    lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
    lIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  sFileName := 'Ping.xml';
  slRequest := TStringList.Create;
  try
    slRequest.LoadFromFile(sFileName);
    lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    lHTTP.Intercept := IdLogDebug1;
    lIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    try
      lHTTP.IOHandler := lIOHandler;
      sResponse := lHTTP.Post('https://FSETTESTPROD.EDD.CA.GOV/fsetservice', slRequest);
      Memo1.Lines.Text := sResponse;
    finally
      lIOHandler.Free;
    end;
  finally
    slRequest.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Edit:  If I don't use the proxy for Fiddler and click the button while Wireshark is running, I get this traffic in Wireshark.
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set Indy to use the proxy fiddler provides easily by setting the ProxyParams:

```
try
  lHTTP.IOHandler := lIOHandler;
  lHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := '127.0.0.1';
  lHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 8888;
  sResponse := lHTTP.Post('<URL>', slRequest);
  Memo1.Lines.Text := sResponse;
finally
  lIOHandler.Free;
end;
```

You should be able to see all traffic in Fiddler then.

Edit: If that does not work you can add a TIdLogDebug component and add it as interceptor (like you did in your question).
The OnReceive and OnSend events contain the complete headers sent and received aswell as the reply data:

```
procedure TForm10.captureTraffic(ASender: TIdConnectionIntercept; 
  var ABuffer: TArray<Byte>);
var
  i: Integer;
  s: String;
begin
  s := '';

  for i := Low(ABuffer) to High(ABuffer) do
    s := s + chr(ABuffer[i]);

  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
end;
```

Comment: I thought it ought to work that way, but I get an error message in Fiddler when I do that that says "Fiddler has detected a protocol violation in session #2.  Content-Length mismatch: Request Header indicated 2,208 bytes, but client sent 0 bytes.".  If I check slRequest before the post, it has data in it.

Comment: I forgot to say that my program freezes on the Post line.  When I kill the program, I get the error message.

Comment: Do you have OpenSSL installed on your machine? Indy requires the binary. Also, the page in your original question returns a 404 error for me.

Comment: When `ProxyParams` is used, `TIdHTTP` connects to the proxy and sends a `CONNECT` request before then sending the `POST` command.  `TIdHTTP` definately sends the post data, so I would suspect a Fiddler issue, not a TIdHTTP issue.  I would suggest using Wireshark to verify what `TIdHTTP` is actually sending.

Comment: @Chris I do have OpenSSL installed and I have the two dll's in the application folder.  You are right about the 404.  I get that also if I try it with Chrome.  If I take the fsetservice off the end, then I message in Chrome that the page is available.  I will leave off the fsetservice.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: The problem with Wireshark is that you can't decrypt the SSL traffic unless you know the private key of the certificate. Fiddler can, because it does not capture the traffic but acts as a proxy.

Comment: Please see my edit to my question.  I added a screen print of the Wireshark traffic.  There are definitely some messages being passed.  It would be helpful to see the HTTP for debugging once the communication layer is established.

Comment: Like I wrote in my previous comment you will only see encrypted traffic in wireshark unless you know the private key of the SSL certificate on the server. I tried it myself (Indy 10 on Delphi XE2), and it worked for me both with a test-page and your URL in the question using Fiddler. It's definetly a Fiddler issue, so if updating to the latest version doesn't help you can only 'manually' capture and analyse the traffic (printing out headers and data sent and received).

Comment: I would be OK with dumping the headers except that I am inexperienced enough with Indy that I am not really sure how to do that.  I experimented with TIdLogDebug.  In the OnSend event, I can see my message but no headers.  In the OnReceive event, I can see the message from that site indicating that it is available.

Comment: @jrodenhi I edited my answer to show sample code for the OnSend and OnReceive events.

Comment: @Chris This is a good workaround for my question.  I don't know why Fiddler is not working, but this gives me all the information I should need to start making some progress.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Do not use the `TStrings` version of `TIdHTTP.Post()` to post XML data. That version of `Post()` is not meant to handle that kind of data, as it encodes the `TStrings` data in a way that will break the XML. Use the `TStream` version of `Post()` instead, which will send the raw XML data as-is without encoding it.

Comment: From what I can remember, turning off the "show a message when HTTP protocol violations encountered" in Fiddler may help.